# Are Normed linear spaces $T_4$(Normal Hausdorff)?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

Do normed linear spaces have the properties of a normal hausdorff space?

---

I just sat an exam and I couldn't work out how to prove something initially, then I assumed that normed linear spaces are $T_4$, and the proof was easy. Are they? Please say yes :)

---

The proof for the record was showing that if we have some normed linear space $X$, and the unit ball on this space has a compact surface, prove that $X$ is not infinite dimensional. Which after the exam I realized was a consequence of Riesz's lemma. But without that I took an open covering and using my $T_4$ properties there were disjoint open balls covering every element of the compact surface, which would cause contradiction for my finite subcovering over infinite elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every metric space is Hausdorff and $T_4$: Hausdorffness is easy to check. For $T_4$, we use the reciprocal of [Urysohn's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urysohn's_lemma): take $F,K \subset X$ be disjoint closed sets. Then: $$f: X \to \Bbb R \\ f(x) = \frac{{\rm d}(x,F)}{{\rm d}(x,F)+{\rm d}(x,K)}$$ is well-defined, continuous, and $f^{-1}([0,1/2[) \supset F$, $f^{-1}(]1/2,1]) \supset K$ are disjoint open sets (because $[0,1/2[$ and $]1/2,1]$ are open in $[0,1]$).

Normed linear spaces are particular metric spaces, so yes, normed linear spaces are Hausdorff and $T_4$.

Comment: Probably got 100%! Thanks!